# Creating conditional composer requirements

Tags: php, composer-php

I've created my first composer package, which has functionality with both MySQL and MongoDB, however, it doesn't require both. I realized that someone may want to use the package just with one of the two databases, and currently I have:

```
"require": {
    "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.2",
}
```

I'm trying to figure out, is there a way to make a package optional, and if it exists, to autoload certain files? Or am I better off doing something in my code like:

```
if (class_exists('PDO')) {
    // Load MySQL code
}
if (class_exists('MongoClient')) {
    // Load MongoDB code
}
```

Is there another solution I can't thought of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Optional" packages manifest themselves as "suggestions" in the `composer.json`:

```
"suggest": {
    "mongodb/mongodb":"Required to use this package with Mongo DB",
    "ext-pdo": "Required to use this package with MySQL",
    "ext-pdo_mysql": "Required to use this package with MySQL"
}
```

Since these are optional, mere suggestions, your code then needs to take care to wrap optional paths in the appropriate conditionals. This might be a test for the PDO class, a test for a connection object of the required types, etc.

Comment: So if I understand correctly from your answer and some quick googling, `optional` packages don't prompt the user in any way; I'd want to do that in my documentation. Then I'd follow my sudo-code above, checking for if the package is installed somehow and if it is, do 'X'.

Comment: Yes, if you need conditional packages(prompts) you will need to write some custom installer script. But it's less work to just let your app say "install one of the following dependencies with command x". Or just require both from the start and let the user choose which one to use from an environment config. Maybe you should just choose for them?

Comment: Optional "suggestions" do prompt, in a fashion: after all packages are installed or updated, composer emits all suggestions, using the text provided in the composer.json. So, for example, if ext-pdo wasn't installed, composer would emit "Required to use this package with MySQL".

Comment: @René As the MongoDB package requires the installed so/dll, I think requiring it may be a bit too far. But I think between documentation and basic logic, optionals will get installed as necessary.